# See Oracle SQL Developer Procedure's Details in Dbeaver

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, dbeaver

I am new for using DBeaver. Can I see Oracle SQL Developer Procedure's Details in Dbeaver?

like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abLlr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the data dictionary.

---

You can get details of the object using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE  object_name = 'PROCEDURE_NAME';
```

You can get further details on the procedure using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_PROCEDURES
WHERE  object_name = 'PROCEDURE_NAME';
```

You can get even more details on the compilation settings using:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM all_plsql_object_settings
 WHERE name = 'PROCEDURE_NAME'
```

You can combine it all into one query:

```sql
SELECT o.owner,
       o.object_name,
       o.subobject_name,
       o.object_id,
       o.data_object_id,
       o.object_type,
       o.created,
       o.last_ddl_time,
       o.timestamp,
       o.status,
       o.temporary,
       o.generated,
       o.secondary,
       o.namespace,
       o.edition_name,
       s.nls_length_semantics,
       s.plsql_ccflags,
       s.plsql_code_type,
       s.plsql_debug,
       s.plsql_optimize_level,
       s.plsql_warnings
FROM   all_objects o
       LEFT OUTER JOIN all_plsql_object_settings s
       ON (o.owner = s.owner AND o.object_name = s.name AND o.object_type = s.type)
WHERE  o.object_name = 'PROCEDURE_NAME';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vx2gBJtg)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there a way to see not like query row? @MT0

Comment: @SektiAndarbeni It is a query so you are going to see it as a query. The query is also used in SQL Developer, however, there the application has a bit of its user interface to display the data in a different format; if that extra user interface does not exist in DBeaver then there is nothing that you can do except to use the query.